# No "Reply" link in Facebook Messenger after upgrade to iOS 9

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, ios9, facebook-messenger

After upgrading to iOS 9 and updating FacebookSDKs,  **"Reply"** link has disappeared from shared messages. I am using Facebook SDK v4.6.0.

I have configured everything according to  upgrade [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9).

Also URL Types is configure with proper URL Scheme - fb{app_id}, since I can open my app from Safari with that custom scheme.

My application is development mode and roles are set for test users.

Anybody else faced the same problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1598811700382892/

Answer (score 0):

Add an App Store ID to your app in the Facebook Developers console- the iPhone / iPad Store ID field.(https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_FB_APP_ID/settings/).

If you don't yet have an App Store ID (during testing), use another app that is in the store.

On iOS8, the reply button always showed. On iOS9, the reply button stopped showing up until I added an App Store ID in the FB app settings. In other words, the App Store ID is required for Reply to appear on iOS9, but apparently not on iOS8. At least for my user with role of admin of the FB app.